# How to keep plot size constant for two plots?

Tags: matlab

I'm using gramm to make two plots. I'm currently using

```
figure('position',[0,0,1000,1000])
```

So that each plot is graphed into the same size window. All of my fonts are the same size. However, plot A's X axis labels are shorter words than plot B's. This is causing matlab to shrink the size of the axis in plot B so that it can fit inside the window, which is causing plot A and B to be different sizes:

[image]

The actual images are the same size. However, the words take up more space in plot B, and so the actual plot is smaller. How can I tell matlab to keep the actual plots the same size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size for axis object, so change the axis size of Plot A to the axis size of plot B.

Click on Plot B to select it:

```
axisB = gca; % axis object for plot B
axisB.Units = 'pixels'; % or other absolute unit. Default is relative to figure
```

Now click on Plot A to select it:

```
axisA = gca;
axisA.Units = 'pixels'; % set to same unit as axisB
dHeight = axisA.Position(4) - axisB.Position(4);
axisA.Position(4) = axisB.Position(4); % set height of axisA to that of axisB
```

Optionally, you can reduce the figure size for plot A, so it looks better:

```
figA = gcf;
figA.Position(4) = figA.Position(4) - dHeight;
```